# How to construct DFA that L accept : w contain '110' and doesn't contain '010'?

Tags: automata, dfa, formal-languages

L = { w belongs {0,1}* | w contain '110' and doesn't contain '010'}

I need to construct DFA that receives L.

How can I draw a DFA that will do the both of conditions?

hints will be a great help.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 2):

A finite state machine (or automaton) consists of:

- A finite set of symbols, called the "alphabet".
- A finite set of states. There is no information in a state other than its label.
- A transition table, which maps each pair <state, symbol> to a new state.
- The starting state: the name of the state which the machine is in before it reads the first symbol.
- The accepting state set: A subset of the set of states which define a successful match.

The machine starts in the starting state, and then reads each symbol in turn. When it reads a symbol, it uses the transition table to decide which is the next state. When it reaches the end, it announces success if the current state is in the accepting set; otherwise, it announces failure.

In a deterministic finite-state automaton (DFA), the transition table is single-valued and complete; that is, every entry is filled in with exactly one state. (Constructing a DFA usually involves adding a "sink state", which is non-accepting and has a self-transition on every symbol. This state is used to handle inputs which cannot be at the beginning of an accepted input.)

If you have a DFA which recognises a language L, you can construct a DFA for the complement of L by simply replacing the set of accepting states with the set of non-accepting states. So if you have a DFA which recognises any input containing 010, you can construct a DFA which recognises any input which does not contain 010 by using just changing the accepting state list.

If you have two DFAs which recognise the languages L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub>, you can construct a new DFA which recognises only those strings in both L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> -- that is, the intersection L<sub>1</sub> ∩ L<sub>2</sub> -- using the Cartesian product of the two DFAs. In the new machine:

- the alphabet is the intersection of the original alphabets. (Usually, all the alphabets are the same in this operation. I just note this for completeness.)
- the states of the new machine are the Cartesian product of the states of the original machines. In other words, the new states are all the pairs <q<sub>i</sub>, r<sub>j</sub>> where q<sub>i</sub> is a state of the first machine and r<sub>j</sub> is a state of the second machine.
- The transition table is constructed using both original transition tables. If there is a transition in the first machine on symbol α from q<sub>i</sub> to q<sub>i'</sub> and a transition in the second machine on the same symbol α from r<sub>j</sub> to r<sub>j'</sub>, then in the combined machine there is a transition on α from <q<sub>i</sub>, r<sub>j</sub>> to <q<sub>i'</sub>, r<sub>j'</sub>>.
- The starting state of the combined machine is the pair of starting states of the original machines.
- The accepting states of the combined machine are all pairs <q<sub>i</sub>, r<sub>j</sub>> where q<sub>i</sub> is an accepting state of the first machine and r<sub>j</sub> is an accepting state of the second machine.

So if you can construct DFAs for:

- The language of strings which contain 110
- The language of strings which contain 010
  then you can use the above procedures to construct a DFA for the contain 110 and don't contain 010 by using the above two procedures.